# WordPress weird Archive Year bug

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom page template for my archive template. However, when I go to

http://www.myurl.com/news-and-events/?year=2014

The posts are showing up properly. However when I try to go to 2013 (there is one post in that year), it shows my 404 page.

This is a custom developed theme.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Are you sure that the post is in the news-and-events category?

Comment: news-and-events is not a category, it's a page with a page template selected. I am retrieving all posts from a given year, if not there, all posts. The weird thing is that it is working with 2014 as parameter, but its not working with 2013 as param.

Comment: Would it show a 404 page if you try `year=2015`?

Comment: Yup. It's only working with 2014, I can't seem to find a logical reason for this.

Comment: Can you post some of the code for the template file?